# How to simulate text selection in testCafe

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, automated-tests, e2e-testing, testcafe

I have an Ionic/Angular app that reacts to text selections (e.g. for annotation in eBooks). The user can highlight text in the browser, and then a menu pops up (somewhat over-riding / augmenting the browser context menu) to allow actions. I would like to test that feature with testcafe. (The component rendering the text reacts to "selectionchange" events from the browser.)

There appears to be no way to simulate a text selection other than the Select Text command (https://devexpress.github.io/testcafe/documentation/test-api/actions/select-text.html), but this is limited to inputs, textareas, or contenteditables. My text is none of those - it's straight

elements.

Any suggestions on how this might be accomplished?

Answer (score 9):

You are right, the SelectText command is limited to inputs, textareas and contenteditable elements. You can solve the issue with the [ClientFunctions](http://devexpress.github.io/testcafe/documentation/test-api/obtaining-data-from-the-client.html) mechanism if you implement your own ClientFunction with custom selection logic using the [Selection API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Selection).
I have prepared an example. If you need to select separate parts of text content, modify it as needed.

```js
import { Selector, ClientFunction } from 'testcafe';

fixture `selection`
    .page `http://example.com`;

const selectElement = (selector) => ClientFunction(() => {
    const selection = document.getSelection();
    const range = document.createRange();

    range.selectNode(selector());
    selection.addRange(range);
}, { dependencies: { selector } });

test('selection', async t => {
    await selectElement(Selector('h1'))();

    await t.debug();
});
```